# S3 Data Sync between two different accounts

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to sync to different account s3 data. A is a source bucket account and B is the destination bucket account.
So A will get files every day every hour and I want to copy the same thing to B from A.

And I want to automate this process in what way will be the best.

Example

```
Account A
<source bucket>/<folder1>/<data>

Account B
<destination bucket><want to get the data from A whenever it gets a file>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can enable S3 [Replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication.html) for the bucket A into bucket B. The buckets can be in different accounts and/or regions.

Comment: how the file transfer will happen\

Comment: @DuskyDood It will happen automatically.

Comment: by enabling versioning option will it affect the folder name in the buckets?

Comment: no. I suggest you to read up a bit how s3, versioning and replication. cross-account access work. You can also do some expermiantation, with some tests buckets.

Comment: I want to replicate source data into an existing bucket, it's not working for me in an existing bucket. If I create a new bucket it's working